# Using scons to buil for gem5 on Windows fails with "No module named 'm5.util'"

Tags: python, windows, scons, gem5

I want to use gem5 and for that, I followed a tutorial that had me download scons and install it with python. Scons seems to work on its own. But when I try to do this step:

```
cd gem5
scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j <NUMBER OF CPUs ON YOUR PLATFORM>
```

I get this error:

```
*** Error loading site_init file .\site_scons\site_init.py:
*** cannot import site init file .\site_scons\site_init.py:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'm5.util':
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Script\Main.py", line 1391:
    _exec_main(parser, values)
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Script\Main.py", line 1355:
    _main(parser)
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Script\Main.py", line 978:
    _load_all_site_scons_dirs(d.get_internal_path())
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Script\Main.py", line 824:
    _load_site_scons_dir(d)
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Script\Main.py", line 762:
    exec(codeobj, site_m)
  File "site_init", line 46:

  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 659:
    env = self.factory()
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 639:
    default_env = SCons.Defaults.DefaultEnvironment()
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Defaults.py", line 86:
    _default_env = SCons.Environment.Environment(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Environment.py", line 999:
    apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Environment.py", line 102:
    env.Tool(tool)
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Environment.py", line 1844:
    tool(self)
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Tool\__init__.py", line 269:
    self.generate(env, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Elif\gem5\site_scons\site_tools\default.py", line 89:
    SCons.Tool.Tool(tool)(env)
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Tool\__init__.py", line 119:
    module = self._tool_module()
  File "C:\Users\Elif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Tool\__init__.py", line 205:
    module = spec.loader.load_module(spec.name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407:

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907:

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732:

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265:

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696:

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677:

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728:

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219:

  File "C:\Users\Elif\gem5\site_scons\site_tools\git.py", line 45:
    import gem5_scons.util
  File "C:\Users\Elif\gem5\site_scons\gem5_scons\__init__.py", line 46:
    from gem5_scons.util import get_termcap
  File "C:\Users\Elif\gem5\site_scons\gem5_scons\util.py", line 45:
    import m5.util.terminal
```

I had a prior error with only "m5" but I tried installing it and now I get "m5.util" error insted. What could be causing this, how do I fix it?
Edit: I'm using Python 3.7.0

Comment: Please add URL to sources you're trying to build.

Comment: I don't think anyone is testing gem5 on Windows BTW. It has POSIX dependencies for sure, so at the very least you would need something like cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem too. Maybe it is due to my source code was copied from another computer.

My solution is just to git clone gem5 source and compiles once again.

```
git clone https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5
# or
git clone https://github.com/gem5/gem5.git
```

Compile again, and this time there is no problem.